# Closing a Modal by passing state between components

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, bootstrap-modal

Currently I have a modal that is opened when a ListItem is clicked inside the ListGroup.tsx, however when I try to pass the state of the modal to my TestGroup component to close the modal it does not perform the expected behaviour.

My thoughts were to render the ListGroup.tsx after the close button is clicked inside the TestGroup.tsx but I'm not sure that makes sense. As the `this.props.onUpdateModal(false);`
should close the modal unless I am missing something.

All code provided are snippets and not complete code.

This is my ListGroup.tsx

```
interface IProps {
  onUpdateModal: typeof UpdateModal;
  showModalState: boolean;
}

export class ListGroup extends React.Component<IProps> {
  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul
          className="list-group"
          style={{
            display: "inline-block",
            marginTop: "20px"
          }}
        >
          {filterTest.map(filterTest => (
            <li
              key={filterTest.companyPN + "-" + filterTest.rev}
              className="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"
              onClick={() => {
                this.props.onUpdateSelectedTest(filterTest);
                this.props.onUpdateModal(true);
              }}
            >
              {filterTest.companyPN}: {filterTest.description}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
        {/* Show the modal if showModal is true */}
        {this.props.showModalState && (
          <TestGroup
            onUpdateModal={this.props.onUpdateModal}
            showModalState={this.props.showModalState}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is my TestGroup.tsx

```
interface IProps {

  onUpdateModal: typeof UpdateModal;
  showModalState: boolean;
}

export class WedgeGroup extends React.Component<IProps> {
  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="modal" style={{ display: "inline-block" }}>
          <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
            {selectedtest.map(selecttest => (
              <div className="modal-content">
                <div className="modal-header">
                  <h5 className="modal-title">test</h5>
                  <button
                    onClick={() => {
                      this.props.onUpdateModal(false);
                    }}
                    type="button"
                    className="close"
                    data-dismiss="modal"
                    aria-label="Close"
                  >
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>

                <div className="modal-body">
                  <p>{selecttest.description}</p>
                </div>
                {/* Close the modal if showModal is false */}
                <div className="modal-footer">
                  <button
                    onClick={() => {
                      this.props.onUpdateModal(false);
                    }}
                    type="button"
                    className="btn btn-secondary"
                    data-dismiss="modal"
                  >
                    Close
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TestGroup;
```

This is my ModalReducer.ts

```
import { ModalActionTypes, SHOW_MODAL } from "../actions/ModalTypes";

const initialState: boolean = false;

export function modalReducer(state = initialState, action: ModalActionTypes) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SHOW_MODAL:
      return {
        showModal: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

This is my ModalActions.ts

```
import { SHOW_MODAL, ModalActionTypes } from "./ModalTypes";

export function UpdateModal(modal: boolean): ModalActionTypes {
  return {
    type: SHOW_MODAL,
    payload: modal
  };
}
```

This is my ModalTypes.ts

```
export const SHOW_MODAL = "SHOW_MODAL";

interface ShowModal {
  type: typeof SHOW_MODAL;
  payload: boolean;
}

export type ModalActionTypes = ShowModal;
```

Comment: are you sure you are getting the correct value in `showModalState` from reduxstate. try console.logging it

Comment: Yeah I get the correct value. When I first open the modal the state updates to true. When I close the modal the state updates to false.

Answer (score 0):

I added another action to hide the Modal and it solved the problem.